# How to toggle colors in list in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a tree-view component:

```
<template>
    <li class="main__li list" :style="{'margin-left': `${depth * 20}px` ,'background-color': `${col}`}" @click="toggle(e); getEl($event)" :title="tree.name">{{tree.name}} </li>
  <ul v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder" class="ul__ctg list">
    <TreeView :tree="chld" v-for="(chld, inx) in tree.children" :key="inx" :depth="depth +1"></TreeView>
  </ul>
</template>
```

my not working script:

```
     getEl(e){
        this.col = 'blue'
        //how turn previous item`s color back?
        return this.tree.id
      },
```

I just want to toggle the item's color, which I choosed, that is when I click an item(im my code this item has @click event) I want to this item change its color to another, but it`s huge problem to me to turn back previous item to initial color. I`ve struggled many hours on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, You have to add default color initially to your every tree object and then on click you can perform toggle.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    trees: [{
        name: 'Tree 1'
    }, {
        name: 'Tree 2'
    }, {
        name: 'Tree 3'
    }, {
        name: 'Tree 4'
    }],
    defaultColor: 'green'
  },
  mounted() {
    this.trees = this.trees.map(obj => {
        obj.color = this.defaultColor;
      return obj;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    getEl(index) {
        const changedColor = 'blue';
        this.trees = this.trees.map((obj, i) => {
            obj.color = (i === index) ? changedColor : this.defaultColor;
          return obj;
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="(tree, index) in trees" :key="index" :style="{'background-color': `${tree.color}`}" @click="getEl(index)">{{tree.name}} </li>
</div>
```

Comment: bro, that doesn`t work. I have an <ul> list with many nested <ul>/<li> and when I change color of one li, I want to previous li color turn back to default. This gonna reflect picking certain category. Wnen you pick one, all others should change their color to default.

Comment: @Netervey I updated my answer as per your exact requirement. Hope it will work now as per your expectation.